# How to retrieve only 1 month from Sq-lite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to retrieve only one-month data form SQLite. Means I want retrieve data from starting of the month to till now. If the new month is stared it should show data of that month only.

Here's my code :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.MONEY + " REAL NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.CAT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,"
                + Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" + "); ";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Query:

```
private Cursor getAllCurrentData()
    {
        String[] selectArg = new String[]{};

        return db.query(Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TABLE_NAME,
                null ,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ ">= strftime('%d','now');",
                selectArg,
                null,
                null,
                Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.TIMESTAMP);
    }
```

This my query for retrieving one-month data. The problem with it is its retrieving previous month data also.
How can I fix that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add 2 conditions in the query. For Ex.

```
Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ "<= strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now') and Db_Contract.Db_Fieds.DATE+ ">= strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', 'start of month');"
```